# Only some files generate when i install jekyll

Tags: html, css, web, jekyll

I don't think this is even where I am supposed to ask about this, but maybe some people on here may know the answer. I am trying to generate and deploy a site using Jekyll, however I ran into an issue.

I use Windows 10, and I use Command Prompt for this, but I did everything necessary for installing the gem, I look at the folder it generated and I dont have every file. I only have:

```
_posts
_config.yml
404
about.md
Gemfile
Gemfile.lock
index.md
```

Why are the other folders not generated? `css`, `index.html`, `_layouts`, etc.?

Is it because these were just in previous versions of Jekyll and they aren't there anymore?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are misunderstanding how jekyll builds the site. Basically you just need to run

```
jekyll build
```

which will generate all necessary files and put them under **_site folder**. You can find more details in [documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/usage/).

Answer (score 0):

The _layouts directory is optional. You can create it yourself. Just make sure it has the right name. The CSS directory is not part of Jekyll at all. The index.html file will be generated in the _site folder (.md is converted to .html).